# Webiew load URL issue

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

This is my url that I want to open in webview but its show different UI rather than the chrome or mozila browser.

http://www.nigeriatoday.ng/

Try to open it in webview and browser and you know the difference.

I need same like browser. Please help me. It would be appreciatable.

WebSettings settings = webvw.getSettings();

```
    webvw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webvw.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webvw.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webvw.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webvw.loadUrl(Url);
```

Thanks

Comment: It's called mobile and desktop version.

Comment: If we open it in mobile chrome or mozila or safari then its good but its UI is differently in mobile webview

Comment: How does your WebView code look like?

Comment: WebSettings settings = webvw.getSettings();
  webvw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  webvw.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  webvw.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webvw.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
  webvw.loadUrl(Url);

Answer (score 0):

As Murat said, You have different look and feel for Mobile version and desktop version.

If you have any specific requirement that you need to display Web content with desktop version on webview, then you can use below code.

String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    webvw.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);

You can see below output...

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help me.

Comment: http://www.nigeriatoday.ng/. You can open this link in mobile web browser and see the UI of it and I need that one UI in webview.